# Force open link in Safari (not Chrome or another browser) from HTML5 app on iPhones and iPads?

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, safari, mobile-safari

Let's say someone is viewing our website with Chrome on his/her iPhone. Is there a way to force a link to open in Safari instead of Chrome? We would like to do this to help users install our HTML5 app. We know application URLs can open specific apps. Does Safari have its own application URL?

Thanks.

Comment: I found this post for a Chrome "Open in Safari" bookmarklet, which might help. I'm trying to solve the same problem. http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/chrome-for-ios-send-a-webpage-back-to-safari-via-bookmarklet/